# how to run an application with the help of junit and ant only while there is no (run) launch config

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant, junit

i have one of my client project, for maintenance.  
it's a big project ever i had. 
here is *** junit and ant**  going to use by my client on that web project. 
i import this project in  **eclipse**  and try to run this on server, but there is no option like i earlier had "run on server" 
may be we can run it only by using  **ant**  and  **junit** . 
i'm really new for that. 
is there anyone who can tell me step by step process how to run this project using eclipse. 
may be i'm asking a stupid question cause of i'm novice but it's really importent for me. 
i'm looking for someone who can help me. 
a big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you need to import into eclipse as a web application.

See if you have this property when you are importing it.
Or try to right click in you project and give it a web application facet.

Comment: i have imported this project as a web application only.

Comment: Try do right click on your project. Then enter project facet and try to add the runtime server you are using.

Comment: i have all ready mention
>i have imported this project as a web application only.
>i'm using tomcat 7 with my eclipse.
> but while i try to run this and right click on project there is no option available like "run on server"
>so i think we can run this project through ant only.

Comment: i searched on net and what i found-
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680257/trying-to-run-ant-junit-target-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse) *

Comment: But I think that if it's a project that is already done and you are doing maintenance, than the Ant file should be provided within the workspace.